# Perl's backticks not working on Windows but works fine on Linux

Tags: windows, perl, ubuntu

I have simple script `perlSample.pl` which print date and time only:

```
my $cmd = 'perl -e \'my $datestring = localtime( time );print $datestring\'';
my $line = `$cmd 2>&1`;
my $ret = $?;
print $line;
```

This script is working fine in Ubuntu but when I run on Windows Xp its give me error:

```
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.
```

On Windows XP I have the ActivePerl (v5.20.1) and Ubuntu (v5.20.1) same version. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Regarding perl -e syntax, perlrun says "On some systems, you may have to change single-quotes to double ones,which you must *not* do on Unix or Plan 9 systems...The problem is that none of this is reliable: it depends on the command and it is entirely possible neither works."

Comment: So, Can we check `OS-TYPE` first and based on that we can execute the part of the script suitable for the target OS?

Comment: Why you execute code in backticks?

Comment: $^O or $Config{'osname'} gives the generic name of the OS which is usually enough.  For more precision, if it returns "linux" for example, POSIX::uname could be used to get any combo of system name, node name, release, version and machine name. For most Windows versions $^O returns "MSWin32" but they can be distinguished by the 5th field of Win32::GetOSVersion(). See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#DOS-and-Derivatives.

Comment: I'm assuming that the `$cmd` is just an example. ( One which could be replaced with just `"perl -e 'print scalar localtime'"` )

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve can be much simpler and portable without the need of calling external instance of perl interpreter,

```
my $line = localtime( time );
print $line;
```

but if you for some reason insist on it, you have to use double quotes under win32, `perl -e ".."`

```
my $cmd = 'perl -e "my $datestring = localtime( time );print $datestring"';
my $line = `$cmd 2>&1`;
my $ret = $?;
print $line;
```

Comment: Thanks,Yeah for some reason only I need to externalize command in `$cmd`. But do I need to change the code every time if I change the OS?

Comment: @snoop you can make perl module so external command can be (and should be) avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I found that
    my $cmd = "perl -e print(localtime(time))";
works fine on Windows 7 at least - don't have WindowsXP any more.

That enables externalizing the command for use in Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

`my $cmd = 'perl -e "my $datestring = localtime( time );print $datestring"';`
`my $line =`$cmd 2>&1`;`
`my $ret = $?;`
`print "$line $ret";`

> single quotes will not work in windows command line you have to use the double quotes to get the same result in windows

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [module](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Cmd.html) which handles quoting the arguments for you.

```
use IPC::Cmd qw' run ';

# prints to STDERR as an example
my @cmd = ('perl', '-e', 'print STDERR scalar localtime');

my $lines; # the output buffer

# buffer gets both STDOUT and STDERR
run( command => \@cmd, buffer => \$lines );

print $lines, "\n";
```

This has the benefit that it comes with Perl, and it quotes the command appropriately for your platform.

---

The way you would do this in Perl6 is a bit different, as it doesn't come with [IPC::Cmd](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Cmd.html), instead you would most likely use the built-in [Proc::Async](http://doc.perl6.org/type/Proc::Async) module.

```perl6
#! /usr/bin/env perl6

use v6; # provides a good error message on Perl 5.8 and newer

my $process = Proc::Async.new('perl6', '-e', '$*ERR.say: DateTime.now');

my @parts;

$process.stdout.tap: { @parts.push('STDOUT' => $_) unless /^ \s* $/ } #;
$process.stderr.tap( { @parts.push('STDERR' => $_) unless /^ \s* $/ } );
# you can "tap" the stderr and stdout Supplys multiple times if you want

{
  my $promise = $process.start;
  # can do other things here, while we wait

  # halt this program until the other one finishes
  await $promise;
}

.say for @parts;
```

```sh
STDERR => 2015-01-26T10:05:42-0600
```

As you can see using the [Proc::Async](http://doc.perl6.org/type/Proc::Async) module requires a bit more code, but it makes up for it by being more flexible.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this script in Linux (Ubuntu) but the execution got hanged. No output no error on the terminal no prompt.

Comment: @snoop I must have been programming in Perl6 too much recently (or I'm too tired at 3am), I forgot that you have to use `(` and `)` in this construct. It should work now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working now only `(` and `)` was missing that's why not working previously. This script works in Perl 5 also.

Comment: @snoop Actually it doesn't work in Perl6 at all (it was just a thinko). Mainly because there isn't a Perl6 version of IPC::Cmd. Very little Perl code will work on both Perl5 and Perl6. That is because Perl6 is almost a completely new language.

Comment: Then better I should use to Perl 5 only.

Comment: @snoop Actually Perl6 comes with [Proc::Async](http://doc.perl6.org/type/Proc::Async "$|  p6doc Proc::Async") built-in which is more flexible than [IPC::Cmd](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Cmd.html "$|  perldoc IPC::Cmd").